# Publishing paid iOS apps or having iAds outside of US

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, iad

I am starting to develop iPhone apps, and I would like to sign the contracts that regulate the opportunity to publish paid apps or use the iAd feature. However, when I go to the right area of the developer page, I only get to options: US, and Canada. When clicking the former, I am requested to sign a W-9 which I cannot do because I am not a 'U.S Person.'

This might be perhaps because I signed up to the developer account with an ID that has a US Address (my home when I am there), but now I cannot find a way to change it.

Would anybody know what I can do to start using this features?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should [contact Apple directly](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wa/jumpTo?page=contactUs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you and one of the comments pointed out, this is due to the fact that your address is in the US. I have an address outside the US, but was prompted to sign the US Agreement however without a W9 form. Therefore contact dev support directly and then ask them to change it, so that you can sign up to. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you by any chance know if I would be able to sign the tax agreement of my country (Venezuela), but still include a bank account in the U.S.? I would like to do this because due to the political situation here, we have several controlled exchange rates, the official one being 10 times lower than the others (which rule the market here).

Comment: Look, you will still sign the US agreement, as it specifically tells you to, but you won't fill out the W-9 forms. Then you can simply list your bank account in the section that you fill in your bank account. If I helped please consider accepting my answer. Thanks!